# Java 8 is not supported in Protege 3.x and 4.x; Protege 5 supports Java 8 but we can not create rules

Tags: java, java-8, ontology, protege, swrl

After upgrading to Java 8 I have come across an issue that my previous versions of Protege (i.e. 3.x and 4.x) do no support Java 8. I can continue with  Protege 5, which supports Java 8, but there is a bug that prevents writing rules. The only solution I have found is to unstall Java 8 (and install Java 7 if you installed it before). I would like to work with Java 8 because I have other Java projects which can avail from it. Please let me know if you have found solutions to either working with Protege 3.x and 4.x in Java 8 or creating rules in Protege 5.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you get with rules? Is there a bug raised with protégé or the owl API?

Comment: Rules works with protege 4.x but not with 5 (Does the rule creation work in Protege 5 in your installation?) . We get the following error message. Error 2 Logged at Tue Sep 30 18:23:13 BST 2014
OWLRuntimeException: org.protege.editor.owl.model.classexpression.OWLExpressionParserException: Encountered Rule at line 1 column 1. Expected one of:
 Rule:    org.protege.editor.owl.ui.editor.SWRLRuleEditor.getEditedObject(SWRLRuleEditor.java:86)

Comment: Sounds like a manchester syntax parsing bug. Can you raise this as a bug on the OWLAPI site? https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues If not, can you provide the rule you are entering, or the ontology as it is saved by Protege 4? (I need one of these to be able to replicate this) Addressing this bug will also allow you to use Protege 5 and Java 8

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to downgrade your java.
Just download the latest version of felix from [here](http://felix.apache.org/)
and then replace the felix.jar  from the bin folder of downloaded file with the current felix.jar file in your protege application directory in bin folder and it will run easily.

Goodluck